# Javascript's Date object weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to create a Date() object from a date formatted dd/mm/yyyy and sometimes it works and sometimes it's doesn't. For example:

```
new Date('12/05/2008 00:00:00'); //OK
new Date('13/05/2008 00:00:00'); //Invalid Date????
```

I happens again in a few specific dates. Am I missing something?

Another thins is when I try to get the js timestamp of created date it acts weird too.

```
(new Date('12/05/2008 00:00:00')).getTime() //Returns 1228428000000
(new Date('01/06/2008 00:00:00')).getTime() //Returns 1199570400000
```

So somehow more time as passed between 1/1/1970 to 12/05/2008 than 1/1/1970 to 01/06/2008?

Comment: The 13th month does not exist. And yes, 6th january was before 5th december.

Comment: Ye I tought it  parsed dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date constructor expects strings of that format to follow the North American convention for writing dates (mm/dd/yyyy) rather than the one used by most other countries (dd/mm/yyyy) so you need to convert between them:

```
var date = '22/05/13'; // today's date according to me (I'm British)

date = date.split('/');
date = date[1]+'/'+date[0]+'/'+date[2];

console.log(new Date(date).toString());
```

However, to avoid ambiguity you might want to use another way of entering the date:

```
var year = 2013, 
    month = 4, // note that months are 0-based when using this approach (i.e. Jan = 0) 
    day = 22;
new Date(year, month, day);
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript generates date as per the localization. I guess your local datetime format is set to MM/dd/yyyy instead of dd/MM/yyyy.

so you are able to parse

```
new Date('12/05/2008 00:00:00');
```

but not

```
new Date('13/05/2008 00:00:00');
```

see here 13 is invalid month.

Comment: It is not true. `Date.parse()` doesn't work with your localization: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse.

Answer (score 0):

It's interpting the format as `MM/dd/yyyy` not the format you think. So in your first example `13/05/2008` is really the 13th month which doesn't exist.